# Inbound Istio Ingress Gateway Metrics

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I deployed a custom Istio Ingress Gateway deployment with the default `IstioOperator` telemetry config and no `EnvoyFilter` to modify the stats.

When I checked the Prometheus stats via:

```sh
kubectl exec -n web-ingress-gateway web-ingress-gateway-6966569988-876mp -c istio-proxy -- pilot-agent request GET /stats/prometheus | grep istio_requests_total
```

It returns a bunch of

```
istio_requests_total{response_code="200",reporter="source",source_workload="web-ingress-gateway",source_workload_namespace="web-ingress-gateway",source_principal="unknown",source_app="web-ingress-gateway",source_version="unknown",source_cluster="redacted",destination_workload="redacted",destination_workload_namespace="redacted",destination_principal="unknown",destination_app="unknown",destination_version="unknown",destination_service="redacted",destination_service_name="redacted",destination_service_namespace="redacted",destination_cluster="redacted",request_protocol="http",response_flags="-",grpc_response_status="",connection_security_policy="unknown",source_canonical_service="web-ingress-gateway",destination_canonical_service="redacted",source_canonical_revision="latest",destination_canonical_revision="latest"} 28
...
```

It seems that only `reporter="source"` labels are there, but no `reporter="destionation"` which is usually also present in the sidecar.

Is there a way to get the incoming requests metrics?

I followed [this doc](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Envoy-native-telemetry).

But it does not really break down to the detail that I need, as it only gives you the `response_code_class` only.

```
# TYPE envoy_http_outbound_0_0_0_0_9282_downstream_rq counter
envoy_http_outbound_0_0_0_0_9282_downstream_rq{response_code_class="1xx"} 0
envoy_http_outbound_0_0_0_0_9282_downstream_rq{response_code_class="2xx"} 1062279
envoy_http_outbound_0_0_0_0_9282_downstream_rq{response_code_class="3xx"} 130245
envoy_http_outbound_0_0_0_0_9282_downstream_rq{response_code_class="4xx"} 12532
envoy_http_outbound_0_0_0_0_9282_downstream_rq{response_code_class="5xx"} 578
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/metrics/#labels):

> **Reporter**: This identifies the reporter of the request. It is set to `destination` if report is from a server Istio proxy and `source` if report is from a client Istio proxy or a gateway.

This means that requests with `reporter="source"` are sent from source pod (web-ingress-gateway in your case), and reported by prometheus as such in this pod.

Requests with `reporter="destination"` are sent from another pod to a desitnation pod in your case (that would be web-ingress-gateway -> ), and are reported as such in the destination pod.

If you issue the same command, but to the application pod (not ingress-gateway), you will see requests with `reporter="destination"`.

Using the [Bookinfo](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/) application as an example, we can se the requests from `productpage` to `details` pods
[image: bookinfo application]

`productpage` is a source pod, and is reported as `reporter="source"`
[image: productpage]

`details` is a destination pod, and is reported as `reporter="destination"`
[image: details]

---

In case I misunderstood your question, and you want to see metrics of requests coming from outside, to your ingress gateway - this is currently not possible. Ingress only emits metrics with reporter as source <sup>[[source](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19237)]</sup>

Comment: Thanks @p10l. I was looking for the metrics of requests coming from outside to your ingress gateway. It seems not available in that case.

Comment: If I have to calculate latency, which one should I consider? reporter=source or reporter=destination? or both will have the same value for latency? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The `reporter="destination"` only available on HTTP connection metric. You need to check your connection protocol. Istio can automatically detect the connection protocol, but when it doesn't it'll default to TCP. Then you need to explicitly select the protocol using name of port or `appProtocol`. See more protocol here https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/

Comment: Not sure if I missed something. I have tried as per your suggestion to explicitly put `appProtocol: http` in the Istio Ingress Gateway's `Service` object, but it did not help. To be in the same page, here I'm looking Istio Ingress Gateway metrics, rather than the normal sidecar.

Comment: @MehdiKhlifi I could not find the solution for this yet. The `reporter="source"` was good enough for us most of the cases.